# Missing $ inserted. problem even there is not one - Error on table

Tags: tables

```
%   This file is part of the APS files in the REVTeX 4.2 distribution.
%   Version 4.2a of REVTeX, December 2014
%

\documentclass[%
 reprint,
%superscriptaddress,
%groupedaddress,
%unsortedaddress,
%runinaddress,
%frontmatterverbose, 
%preprint,
%preprintnumbers,
%nofootinbib,
%nobibnotes,
%bibnotes,
amsmath,amssymb,
aps,
%pra,
%prb,
%rmp,
%prstab,
%prstper,
%floatfix,
]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{float}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2009}{\,} 
\usepackage{physics}
\newcommand{\gsim}{\gtrsim}
\newcommand{\lsim}{\lesssim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}% Enable numbering of text and display math
%\linenumbers\relax % Commence numbering lines

%\usepackage[showframe,%Uncomment any one of the following lines to test 
%%scale=0.7, marginratio={1:1, 2:3}, ignoreall,% default settings
%%text={7in,10in},centering,
%%margin=1.5in,
%%total={6.5in,8.75in}, top=1.2in, left=0.9in, includefoot,
%%height=10in,a5paper,hmargin={3cm,0.8in},
%]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[b]
\caption{\label{tab: Table 2}BAO data used in the analysis \cite{Aubourg_2015}.}
\begin{ruledtabular}
\begin{tabular}{lcdr}
\textrm{Redshift} &
\textrm{Name} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textrm{$D_V/r_d$}} &
\textrm{$D_M/r_d$} \\
\colrule
0.106 & 6dFGS & $3.047 \pm 0.137$ & -\\
0.15  & MGS  & $4.480 \pm 0.168$ & -\\
0.32  & BOSS LOWZ Sample & $8.467 \pm 0.167$ & -\\
0.57  & BOSS CMASS Sample & - & $14.945 \pm 0.210$\\
2.34 & LyaF auto-correlation & -  & $37.675 \pm 2.171$\\
2.36 & LyaF-QSO cross correlation & - & $36.288 \pm 1.344$
\end{tabular}
\end{ruledtabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

I have created a table, however when I run it, it gives missing $ error. Nevertheless I have used the $ in proper ways. Interestingly when I remove the $\pm$ the code works fine. My problem is why the code above does not work properly ?

The output is like [image]

There is missing data so how can I fix it

Comment: I bet your `d` column type switch to math mode ...

Comment: Please tell us how or where the `d` column type is defined. Incidentally, `\textrm{$D_V/r_d$}` and `\textrm{$D_M/r_d$}` cannot be right; it should probably be either `$\textrm{D_V/r_d}$` and `$\textrm{D_M/r_d}$` or, more simply, `$D_V/r_d$` and `$D_M/r_d$`. Of course, if the column is processed in math mode automatically, you should omit the `$` math mode initiators and terminators.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer how can I fix it

Comment: @Mico I edited my post

Comment: Simply remove the $ $ in these cells, `& 8.467 \pm 0.167 &`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks